# How do I write descriptive statistics to the same CSV and TXT files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have ran descriptive statistics on a dataset but I have to write them to a CSV and TXT file. Here is my code so far in that section:

```py
dfst=pd.DataFrame(sk)

print (dfst.describe())

dfstt=pd.DataFrame(ku)

print (dfstt.describe())


dfst.describe().to_csv('skewness_stats.csv',index=True)

dfstt.describe().to_csv('kurtosis_stats.csv', index=True)
```

The DF's run descriptive statistics on Kurtosis and Skewness simulations I ran. I am able to write the statistics to seperate CSV files, but how do I write them to the same one with column headers, etc.? Also unsure how to do the same with a TXT file. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You export the two data frames as CSV to memory, then write the two strings into the same file:

```py
from io import StringIO

# To pandas, these two look just like any regular file
# In reality, they are stored in memory instead of disk
skewness = StringIO()
kurtosis = StringIO()

dfst.describe().to_csv(skewness)
dfstt.describe().to_csv(kurtosis)

with open('statistics.csv', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(skewness.getvalue())
    fp.write('\n')
    fp.write(kurtosis.getvalue())

skewness.close()
kurtosis.close()
```

Comment: I am now getting this error message  - object of type '_io.StringIO' has no len(). It is on a line relating to the graph this data represents.